# MySQL: GROUP BY specific time periods (overlapping days)

Tags: mysql, time, group-by

I have a table, storing years of weatherdata in 5 minute periods. Now I need a result, with the lowest temperature, for each period from 8pm to 8am next day.

Or in other words: lowest temperature from every night (20:00 - 08:00).

Table:

```
datetime            temp
2015-04-01 00:00    21.2
2015-04-01 00:05    21.1
2015-04-01 00:10    20.8
...
2015-04-02 00:00    22.6
2015-04-02 00:05    22.2
```

my very basic approach is:

```
SELECT MIN(temp) 
FROM weathertable 
WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2015-04-01 18:00' AND '2015-04-02 08:00'
```

But i need a result for every period without fixed dates.

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   MIN(temp)
FROM 
   weathertable
WHERE 
    TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)-(10*60*60))) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '22:00:00'
GROUP BY 
    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)-(10*60*60)));
```

Comment: Thank you! this seems to work for me, with minor changes. But I don't understand why. Some explanations would maybe help to understand.

here are my changes:
SELECT date(datetime), MIN(temp) FROM wtr2 
WHERE TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)-(12*60*60))) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '20:00:00' 
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)-(12*60*60)))

and this works also:

SELECT date(datetime), MIN(temp) FROM wtr2 
WHERE TIME(datetime - INTERVAL 12 hour) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '20:00:00' 
GROUP BY DATE(datetime - INTERVAL 12 hour)

Comment: I am sorry that I have not written description
In the GROUP statement I push for any length of time, this can be for us what is important is that we can group per day so
Who should choose in the WHERE statement to which hours you are interested in. Once again "push" the amount of time you can use the BETWEEN operator, or you can use the or operator and the relations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

to get the previous date: **select subdate(curdate(),1);**

```
SELCT min(temp) 
FROM *tablename*
where 
date between 
concat(subdate(curdate(),1),' ','20:00:00') and concat(curdate(),' ','08:00:00');
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I've tried this and it seems to works only for the "latest night". I like to have "all nights" in the result.